# When I add 3rd party dependencies I get failed to resolve errors in android studio, what should I do to fix this?

Tags: android, android-studio

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.4.7'
compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.9.4.7'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

I get the following errors:

[image]

Also pressing the install Repository and Sync project does not do anything so what should I do to fix this. This only happens when I add the material dialog dependencies and works fine without them 2 but I would like to use them in my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code to build.gradle file at application level:

```
allprojects {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
      maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, do you know why it was not working before?

Comment: google created its own maven repository for support libraries.